# QOS Class not getting set for pthread in macOS

Tags: macos, pthreads

I am building a macOS project where I m creating a thread using pthread in cpp. I am setting the QOS class using the **pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np** and later checking the value of the QOS class using the **pthread_attr_get_qos_class_np**. These calls are successful but the QOS class is not being set. Below is the cpp function that I m invoking from my swift code.

```
bool CppThread::CreateThread ()
{
        pthread_t      threadId;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        qos_class_t    qos_class;
        int            relative_priority;
    
    int rc = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    if (rc) {
        
        printf ("pthread_attr_init failed");
    }

    if (pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np (&attr, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 5)) {
        
        printf ("pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np failed\n");
    }

    int retval = pthread_create(&threadId, &attr, threadFunction, NULL);
    if (retval) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating thread" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (pthread_attr_get_qos_class_np (&attr, &qos_class, &relative_priority)) {
        
        printf ("pthread_attr_get_qos_class_np failed\n");
    }

    printf ("QoS class: %d, Relative priority: %d\n", qos_class, relative_priority);
    
    pthread_join(threadId, NULL);  // Wait for thread to finish
    std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

> QoS class: 0, Relative priority: 0
>
> Thread finished

I have tried setting multiple QOS values but the output always shows the QOS class value as 0. Why is it not getting set?

Comment: You are presumably getting stub versions of these functions instead of functional ones.  Aside from the evidence that the QOS class and relative priority you set are not read back correctly, the `pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np()` call ought to be failing with `EINVAL` on account of the specified relative priority exceeding 0.  You probably need (at least) to compile with the `-pthread` option.